# Is there a way to reference field name with a variable in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Is there a way to reference field name with a variable value in Firebird ?
for example I want to make SQL like this:

```
Insert into tab1 (1, f1, f2, f3)
    select 1, tab2.f+var_loop, tab2.f+var_loop, tab2.f+var_loop
    from tab2
    where .....
```

where "f" is the first initial of the field name and "var_loop" is a loop variable 
Thanks

Comment: Having columns with consecutive numbering smells like a really bad database design. Btw: the list of columns for a SELECT does not need to be put into brackets.

Comment: this is an example for people to understand. next time think about what I want with your head not with your nose !!!

Comment: The concatenation of a prefix and a number **will** yield column names like `some_name_1`, `some_name_2`, `some_name_3`. A design like that does smell like it's not normalized. If this is *not* what you have, then you should supply a better (i.e. meaningful) example

Comment: I did not know whether it is possible or not. just a demonstration of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported. I quess you can achieve something like this using [EXECUTE BLOCK](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html), but then you could build the right SQL statement on the client side right away too, would be much easier...

Comment: I need to write it on the server side only

Comment: Define 'server side'. In any case, if you want to do this you *need* execute block.

Comment: need example please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718748/how-to-reference-firled-names-with-variable-in-firebird-stored-proceder-or-execut

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you must write your application code to build the SQL prior to preparing the query.

In SQL, the name and number of columns must be fixed at the time you prepare the query.  Column names can't be based on expressions that aren't evaluated until runtime.  This is true in standard SQL and in every brand of RDBMS as far as I know.

Also you can't use parentheses around a list of column in a SELECT clause as you're doing.

Comment: @Welliam, can you provide a link to documentation or an example of writing SQL with column names that are evaluated at query execute time?  I know one can use dynamic SQL to build a query prior to prepare time.

Comment: Yes, that is possible in any RDBMS, including Firebird.  But it's not the RDBMS that evaluates the expressions to form column names.  Your application code does that, before you prepare the SQL query.