# How to reference field names with variable in Firebird stored procedure or execution block

Tags: sql, firebird

Please give me an example how to reference field names with variable in a Firebird stored procedure or `execute block`

Something like this pseudo SQL:

```
Insert into tab1 (1, f1, f2, f3)
    select 1, tab2.f+var_loop, tab2.f+var_loop, tab2.f+var_loop
    from tab2
    where .....
```

where "f" is the first initial of the field name and "var_loop" is a loop variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not quite clear to me what you want to achieve, but in the PSQL there is also [EXECUTE STATEMENT](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-psql-execstat.html) feature available which might suit your needs - it allows you to buid a string and then execute it as a DSQL statement... Assuming the `var_loop` in your example is integer your code might be something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo(var_loop INTEGER)
AS
DECLARE Stmnt VARCHAR(1024);
BEGIN
  Stmnt = 'Insert into tab1 (1, f1, f2, f3)'||
          'select 1, tab2.f'|| CAST(var_loop AS VARCHAR(10)) ||
          ', tab2.f'|| CAST(var_loop AS VARCHAR(10)) ||
          ', tab2.f'|| CAST(var_loop AS VARCHAR(10)) ||
          'from tab2 where(...)';
  EXECUTE STATEMENT Stmnt;
END^
```

Comment: thanks alot my friend this is what I am looking for although it will be hard for debugging this proc

Comment: @Welliam It is hard too debug, it is also an indication that you may want to use a different table structure which does not require dynamic discovery of the tables or fields to use.