# example for using execute block to insert data using parameters for column names

Tags: sql, firebird

I dont know if this is possible but I am looking for any example using execute block to execute Insert statement and insert data using parameters for column names

pseudo code:

```
  While loop_counter begin

    Insert into table1 (f1+loop_counter, f2+loop_counter, f3+loop_counter, f4+loop_counter)
      values (#,#,#,#)
 end
```

where "f" is the first initial of the field name and "loop_counter" is a loop variable

Thanks

Comment: I thought you got answer for your question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718748/how-to-reference-firled-names-with-variable-in-firebird-stored-procedure-or-exec/7719151#7719151 ? BTW your pseudo code looks wrong - all the fields would have the same name (ie `f1, f1, f1, f1`), sure you'd want something like `f1, f2, f3, f4` instead?

Comment: yes I mean different names and looking for a solution using execute block...thanks

Comment: Please update your question then so it is clear what exactly youre looking for. Also, you want to use it in PSQL (ie in trigger or stored procedure) or in DSQL?

Comment: sorry I dont know how to explain more. I want the same in previous question but using execute block is that possible ? and yes I need it to be PSQL.....thanks

Comment: The execute block is only available in DSQL, see manual: http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html In PSQL you can use `EXECUTE STATEMENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need in EXECUTE STATEMENT operator. Try something like this:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE s VARCHAR(200);
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  WHILE (<some condition with loop_counter>) DO 
  BEGIN
    s = 'INSERT INTO TABLE1 (F1' || 
      loop_counter || ', F2' ||
      loop_counter || ',F3' || 
      loop_counter || ',F4' || 
      loop_counter || ') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    EXECUTE STATEMENT (:S) (#,#,#,#);
    ...
  END
  ...
END
```